# Как передать аттачи через FormData и правильно принять их на php для отправки ф-ей mail()

Tags: javascript, php, formdata

Пытаюсь сделать возможность удалять вложения перед отправкой, и потом отправить. Реализацию нашел, но требуется помощь. Проблема в том, что если я отправляю аттачи как есть, не редактируя - все приходит, как только я что-то удаляю то:

```
var_dump ($_FILES);
```

возвращает ошибку 4.
Насколько я понял, когда разбирался - причина кроется в том что через js получить содержимое input type="files" - можно только для чтения, соответсвенно в моей реализации делается копия этих данных в объект, и предполагается последующая их отправка через FormData. У меня это сделать не получилось, не могу понять где и что нужно править, в php или js, и что именно.

Comment: покажите код отправки

Comment: @Taarim Вот конкретно код отправки
https://jsfiddle.net/ukgro4we/
Полностью код - вот тут:
[Ссылка](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/912180/%D0%9D%D0%B5-%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%83-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB%D1%8B-%D1%81-%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D1%8B)